# Getting Jasmine to run on the server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm trying to get started on testing JavaScript on the server-side with Node.JS

I'm using [**grunt**](http://gruntjs.com), and [**grunt-jasmine-node**](https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node), but I can't get it to run my tests.

It just logs

> PS C:\Development\NET\Source\jsn> grunt Running "jasmine_node" task
>   undefined
>
> Finished in 0.001 seconds 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures
>
> Done, without errors.

This is my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jasmine_node: {
            specNameMatcher: 'spec',
            projectRoot: '.',
            requirejs: false,
            forceExit: true,
            jUnit: {
                report: false,
                savePath : "./build/reports/jasmine/",
                useDotNotation: true,
                consolidate: true
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-node');
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'jasmine_node');
};
```

And my file structure is this:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

It's like the `stub.js` file isn't ever even loaded, because it has a `console.log` call in it to test that.

Comment: I cannot help you with your problem here, but as an alternative, you could try the Jasmine plugin from the Grunt team: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine.

Comment: grunt-contrib-jasmine runs tests in a browser (PhantomJS).  It will not help with running tests on node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

- Make sure the extension to your javascript test specs is **`.spec.js`**

Or

- Replace the configuration option `specNameMatcher` with **`matchall: true`**

Comment: Same here, I am trying to run coffeescript tests in /specs/**/*.coffee and I don't manage. any hint?